# I can't use open3d open obj

Tags: python, open3d

When I use "mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("data/1.obj")",
I get that "[Open3D WARNING] Unable to load file data/1.obj with ASSIMP".
There is no problem loading this obj with numpy. Do anyone know what problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the path is correct. You will need probably something like this:

```
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("../data/1.obj")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when the path of the file has some unicode, it doesn't work in windows os. In this case, before transfer it to the read function, change the encoding style. like this.

```
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(file_path.encode("mbcs"))
```